# Sqlite android: Update successful but new row created

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update, sql-insert

Update method returns true.
But when listing the whole table, new rows were created for each update.

ONE table, three columns: PRIMARY_ID, MY_ID, MY_ANOTHER_ID.

I have the following methods:

```
public void insertOrUpdate(String lStringId){
    boolean present= search(lStringId);
    if(present){
        updateData(lStringId);
    } else{
        insertData(lStringId);
    }
}
```

Search:

```
private boolean search(String lStringId) {
    Cursor cursor = null;
    try {
        cursor = mDatabase.query(TABLE_NAME, null,
                MY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{lStringId}, null, null, null);

        if (null != cursor && cursor.getCount() == 1 && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            return true
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "-search, cursor.getCount() = " + cursor.getCount());

        return false;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "-search, Error: "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
        return false;
    } finally {
        if (null != cursor) {
            cursor.close();
            cursor = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Update:

```
public boolean updateData(String lStringId) {
    Log.d(TAG, " -updateData");
    ContentValues lValues = new ContentValues();
    lValues.put(MY_ANOTHER_ID, lStringId+"extra");
    if (mDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,
            lValues, MY_ID + "= '" + lStringId + "'", null) > 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, " -updateData, true");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Insert:

```
public long insertData(String lStringId) {
    Log.d(TAG, " -insertData");
    ContentValues dataValues = new ContentValues();
    dataValues.put(MY_ID, lStringId);

    long result = mDatabase.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, dataValues);
    Log.d(TAG, "result: " + result);
    return result;
}
```

After the first new insert, the next time I call  **insertOrUpdate** method, **search** method returns true. And **updateData** method was called and it also returns true.

**-search, cursor.getCount() =** also prints 1.

But when I check the contents of the table, there are two rows with same MY_ID value and different MY_ANOTHER_ID values.

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the type of `MY_ID` ? is that Text or Integer type ?

Comment: you can try like this way , 

`mDatabase.update(TABLE_NAME,
            lValues, MY_ID + " = ?", new String[]{lStringId}) `

Comment: @ZahidulIslam MY_ID, MY_ANOTHER_ID both Text

Answer (score 1):

Lot's of things can go wrong here.

**Non atomic operations.**

You are first querying whether an object exists then doing the insert or update. In android it's unlikely that another thread will create another object in between these two operations but in other places it can happen so this is a habit to avoid.

**Unique key on MY_ID, MY_ANOTHER_ID**

If there can only be one MY_ID in that table you should have a unique key on it. If not you should have a together unique key on the my_id, my_another_id pair of columns.

**Code in search method.**

```
 if (null != cursor && cursor.getCount() == 1
      && cursor.moveToFirst())     {
        return true
 }
```

This will return true if there is exactly one record for my_id what if you have two? Then this method will not return true, the calling function will believe there aren't any matching records in that table.

**Insert or Update the real deal**

Android Sqlite supports [ON CONFLICT REPLACE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#CONFLICT_REPLACE). You can simplify your code a great deal by making use of it.

Comment: but the search method returns true when there was already 4 MY_ID values with same values.. but before that, why did the above code created a new row on the second time?

Comment: the above method was access from a single place at a time.. also between consecutive calls there is an interval of atleast 1min

Comment: The atomicity was just something that I warned you to keep in mind when writing this sort of code. As for the search method, obviously cursor.getCount() == 1 if and only if you have exactlly 1 entry in your table. So forgive me for being sceptical on this point.